# Subversion on 1 Gb uplink

Tags: apache-2.2, svn

is it possible at all to utilize 1 Gb uplink? I have 2 server with 1 Gb uplink

**176.9.xxx.xxx - server**

```
# uname -a
Linux svn.example.net 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Mon Sep 23 22:14:43 UTC 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# cat /etc/debian_version
6.0.8

# svnadmin --version
svnadmin, version 1.6.23 (r1485506)
   compiled May 29 2013, 10:00:56

Copyright (C) 2000-2009 CollabNet.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/
This product includes software developed by CollabNet (http://www.Collab.Net/).

The following repository back-end (FS) modules are available:

* fs_base : Module for working with a Berkeley DB repository.
* fs_fs : Module for working with a plain file (FSFS) repository.

# ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: on
    Supports Wake-on: pumbag
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000001 (1)
    Link detected: yes
```

**144.76.xxx.xxx - client**

```
# uname -a
Linux test.example.net 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Nov 22 03:15:09 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

# svnadmin --version
svnadmin, version 1.6.11 (r934486)
compiled Apr 11 2013, 16:13:51

Copyright (C) 2000-2009 CollabNet.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.tigris.org/
This product includes software developed by CollabNet (http://www.Collab.Net/).

The following repository back-end (FS) modules are available:

* fs_base : Module for working with a Berkeley DB repository.
* fs_fs : Module for working with a plain file (FSFS) repository.

# ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                         1000baseT/Full
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                           drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes
```

Some basic tests

```
# iperf -c 176.9.xxx.xxx -t 60
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 176.9.xxx.xxx, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 19.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 144.76.xxx.xxx port 42619 connected with 176.9.xxx.xxx port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-60.0 sec  4.15 GBytes   594 Mbits/sec

# iperf -c 144.76.xxx.xxx -t 60
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 144.76.xxx.xxx, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 16.0 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 176.9.xxx.xxx port 54666 connected with 144.76.xxx.xxx port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-60.0 sec  3.17 GBytes    453 Mbits/sec
```

At the same time when I download some project from svn via http speed is about 100 Mbit/s max. But a plain binary file has been downloaded at max speed

```
# axel -a -v http://176.9.xxx.xxx/test.img
Initializing download: http://176.9.xxx.xxx/test.img
File size: 1101824020 bytes
Opening output file test.img
Starting download

Connection 3 finished                                                          ]
Connection 0 finished                                                          ]
Connection 1 finished                                                          ]
[100%] [..................................................] [  94.3MB/s] [00:00]

Downloaded 1050.8 megabytes in 11 seconds. (96588.44 KB/s)

# wget http://176.9.xxx.xxx/test.img
--2014-02-01 14:21:13--  http://176.9.xxx.xxx/test.img
Connecting to 176.9.xxx.xxx:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1101824020 (1.0G) [text/plain]
Saving to: “test.img”

100%[=================================>] 1,101,824,020 51.0M/s   in 21s

2014-02-01 14:21:34 (49.9 MB/s) - “test.img” saved [1101824020/1101824020]

# curl -o test.img http://176.9.xxx.xxx/test.img
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1050M  100 1050M    0     0  56.8M      0  0:00:18  0:00:18 --:--:-- 57.2M
```

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Update1

As you an see the speed is around 100 Mbit

```
# time svn co http://svn.example.net/Test/ ./Test/
Authentication realm: <http://svn.example.net:80> Authorization required.
Password for 'user':
A    Test/test.img
Checked out revision 1.

real    1m40.768s
user    0m48.885s
sys     0m3.738s
```

[image: download speed from svn]

Update2
The same file but via svn protocol, the speed around 250 Mbit/s

```
# time svn co svn://svn.example.net/ ./Test/
A    Test/test.img
Checked out revision 1.

real    0m46.075s
user    0m15.338s
sys     0m4.811s
```

[image: download speed from svn via svn protocol]

System load during checkout

```
# top
top - 18:26:34 up 60 days, 10:14,  1 user,  load average: 0.25, 0.06, 0.02
Tasks: 214 total,   1 running, 213 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu0  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu1  : 99.0%us,  1.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu2  :  0.0%us,  0.9%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.1%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu3  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu4  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu5  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu6  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu7  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  16377584k total, 15345624k used,  1031960k free,   203640k buffers
Swap:  8388600k total,     1956k used,  8386644k free, 13597864k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
5449 www-data  20   0  409m  68m 3656 S  100  0.4   2:17.41 apache2
6885 root      20   0 10976 1340  944 R    1  0.0   0:00.28 top
```

Answer (score 0):

We know too little about your subversion test to answer the question. Try downloading test.img from the repository after you commited it, it should fully satisfy your connection. My guess is that you are measuring while trying to clone a repository which normally is represented with many individual small files thus making many connections necessary and thus slowing down the transfer.

Comment: I have added additional information to the question. As you can see the problem not in small files.

Comment: Is `svn.example.net` and `176.9.xxx.xxx` the same server _and_ fullfilled through the same interface (just on different ports or something)?

Comment: svn.example.net (svn server) has address 176.9.xxx.xxx, the client (on which I ran svn co) has address 144.76.xxx.xxx

Answer (score 0):

Because you can get good speed with network-only benchmarks it looks like the problem is SVN itself.

SVN is slow.  It does a lot of work when receiving and sending a file.

The processing involves copying the data multiple times: copying from the network buffer to the program's memory; from the program's memory to an outgoing disk buffer; from a disk buffer to the disk.  That's at least 3 copies and if the developer wasn't careful there could be more copies (i.e. extracting the data out of the HTTP stream, decoding it from the SVN file format into plain data, etc).  Programs like cp/wget/rsync are highly optimized and attempt to do zero copies... just manipulate the data in place.

I'm speculating but.... SVN wasn't designed to be fast. It was designed to be reliable.  Therefore keeping things simple (strictly copying data to each layer) is more important than complex algorithms that reduce data copying.

One way you can tell if a program is doing a lot of pre- and post-processing is if the "user" time is high.  In your example the user time was 30% of the time:
    real    1m40.768s
    user    0m48.885s
    sys     0m3.738s
48.885s is about 31% of the total time.  That's a lot of processing for each block of data received.  There is 48.2 seconds of time unaccounted for.  This is the system waiting for disk or networking; which could indicate your storage has slow disks).

Compare to this to copying a big (1382445394 bytes or ~1.3G) file using the highly optimized "cp" command:

```
$ time cp bigfile.mp4 copyofbigfile.mp4

real    0m3.268s
user    0m0.005s
sys     0m0.994s
```

The "user" time is 0.005s. That means "cp" is basically setting up a bunch of parameters and letting the kernel do all the work.  Almost the 70% of the time is spent waiting for disk (and this is on my laptop with all SSDs).

You get better performance using the svn: protocol instead of http:.  That indicates that the HTTP library they are using is reducing performance.  It makes sense that the native protocol is faster.

Your original question was "is it possible at all to utilize 1 Gb uplink?"  I would speculate that the answer is "yes" but you will need to fix the bottleneck.  Switching to the SVN protocol is a good first step.  It looks like faster CPU or faster RAM would help too.

That's my recommendation for 1 file.  If there are multiple files involved then you have a different problem. Between files SVN does other processing.  That might be CPU-bound, but it could be disk bound also (if it is waiting for the file to fsync() before it moves to the next file).  That's an entire different set of benchmarks and analysis to perform.

Comment: As you can see output of the top utility - there is no overload at all. The server has faster CPU - Intel Xeon E3-1245 and 16 Gb of RAM. The disk subsystem is 2 RAID1 on hardware raid controller LSI-9260 with BBU. Is there any sense to test subversion-1.7 or maybe even 1.8? AFAIK svn-1.7 has introduced new http protocol - httpv2.